# URL .htaccess in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Do anyone can give some advice on how to do 

URL for my php page
I have this URL  
website.com/profile.php/8

What I need is this URL

 website.com/profile/8

What I do is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But it / "Backslash" is reading for another directory, any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Forward /profile/8 to /profile.php/8
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php/$2 [L]

# Forward /profile to /profile.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

`RewriteCond` is to ensure corresponding `.php` exists.

Comment: This works can you give a little bit of explain how this works ?

Comment: I wrote few comments before each rule.